# How do you order by 2 meta values in Wordpress?

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

I am using Woocommerce, although my question relates to WP_Query in general. I am creating a custom WP_Query loop for bestselling products and I want to allow users to be able to sort the results by price, from high to low and low to high. The problem is in Woocommerce both _price and total_sales are meta fields and as far as I can tell I can only orderby 1 meta field in Wordpress loops. Is there a way around this?

My [full code including some of my attempts is here](http://pastebin.com/gVyNd65e), the most relevant code segment looks like as follows:

```
$queryArgs = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'           => '_visibility',
                    'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                    'compare'       => 'IN'
                )
            ),
            'meta_key' => '_price',
            'orderby' => array('meta_value_num' => $sortBy['terms'])
        );
```

The actual code is more complicated than this because it's built for a range of filtering and sorting options, but this is the gist of it and bestsellers is the only thing giving me issues because of the two meta_keys. [I've read this](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/) but it doesn't apply to custom meta fields.

I've tried:

```
'meta_key' => '_price total_sales'

'meta_key => array('_price', 'total_sales')
'orderby' => array('meta_value_num' => $sortBy['terms'], 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC')
```

Nothing seems to work. I've also tried hooking onto the various WP_Query filters but the problem is this query is part of a dynamically generated loop so I can't 'hack' or hard-code anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use the meta query with arrays:

```
'meta_query' => array (
            array (
                'key' => '_visibility',
                'value'  => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                'compare' => 'IN'
             ),
            array (
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => "VALUE WHAT YOU WANT, NOT ASC/DESC",
            )
        ),
```

Comment: Hi, I gave this a go but it is not returning any results, here's a pastebin var_dump of the query: http://pastebin.com/zdnaAmvq

Comment: Ok, now i see what the problem is. The `$sortBy['terms']` it is. Move out that to the order section, because `value` need to be your desired value, not `ASC` or `DESC`. I think, price is not `ASC` or `DESC`. See my edited code.

Comment: I appreciate your help but that is my problem, it has to be either ASC or DESC because I need it to sort products by both price and total sales...

Comment: I understood that, what i tried to mention, that is ASC or DESC is not goes into the value field.

Comment: Anyway, then you should write your own plain sql query.